# Open Visual Studio Code Terminal Panel without opening a new Terminal (shortcut maybe)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way/shortcut to open the Visual Studio Code Terminal Panel without opening a new Terminal?

Comment: @rioV8 Precisely what I wanted, I just couldn't find it anywhere! (if you can post this as an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show/hide the Panels (Terminal, Debug Console,...) with the key combo

`Ctrl+J`